# Literal Strings [Lua 5.1]

Tags: string, lua, literals

So I started to learn Lua(5.1) and I saw that thing called literal strings. And I have no idea what these do. The manual says \a is a bell but when I type

```
print('hello\athere')
```

The IDE prints a weird square with 'bel' written on it.
So if someone could help me and explain every one of them[Literal Strings]. that would be really helpful.

p.s. i use Sublime Text 3

Answer (score 4):

Only ASCII between `0x20` and `0x7E` are [printable characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_characters). How other characters are output, including `'\a'` and `'\b'`, is up to the implementation.

`'\a'`, the ASCII `7` for `BEL`, is designed to be used to alert. Typical terminal would make an audible or visible alert when outputing `'\a'`. Your IDE choose to show a different output other than an alert. That's OK since it's up to the implementation.

Answer (score 4):

Such sequences are called "escape sequences", and are found in many different languages. They are used to encode non-printable characters such as newlines in literal (hardcoded) strings.

Lua supports the following escape sequences:

- `\a`: Bell
- `\b`: Backspace
- `\f`: Form feed
- `\n`: Newline
- `\r`: Carriage return
- `\t`: Tab
- `\v`: Vertical tab
- `\\`: Backslash
- `\"`: Double quote
- `\'`: Single quote
- `\nnn`: Octal value (`nnn` is 3 octal digits)
- `\xNN`: Hex value (Lua5.2/LuaJIT, `NN` is two hex digits)

Answer (score 3):

A literal is not more than a value inside the code, e.g.: `'some text'`.

The `'\a'` is something different. A special "char", that is used to output a sound (was using the pc-speaker some aeons ago).