# How to use \a escape sequence

Tags: c++, bash, escaping

I'm studying C++, using bash, and the Escape Sequences.
I'm trying to do a lot of exercises to better memorize them.
Now, the \a should produce a sound, like a beep.

I'm using the following code, but it seems \a doesn't work:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()

 {

   cout << "\a";

   return 0;

 }
```

Did I make any mistake? I'm only using it like the \n sequence, is this wrong?
  Thanks!

New details: I discovered it works on the terminal, but it doesn't work in the built-in terminal in Kate.

OS: I use Ubuntu as a guest Os using Windows 7 as host with VirtualBox.
      I'll post the version soon.

Comment: Can you make a sound from your terminal otherwise?

Comment: Nope, it seems I can't.

Comment: which OS are you running?  The reason that I ask corresponds to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3456167/3259125) in another SO question.  Other response mention the flushing of output .. perhaps you need to add a carriage return/line feed ... same 'no beep' with printf() too?

Comment: I added more details above.

Comment: See [the same question on Lua](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26803512/literal-strings-lua-5-1).

Answer (score 5):

Whether `\a` produces a beep or not depends on where you write it. If you run this program in a Unix terminal you'll probably get a sound. If you use an IDE or a GUI terminal emulator it might happen that you won't see or hear anything.

If you specify which terminal you're using (gnome-terminal? Apple Terminal.app?) someone might help you configuring it to play a sound...

Answer (score 1):

First run `sudo modprobe pcspkr` and then `beep` should work.

If this works for you, then to enable the loading of pcspkr permanently edit the `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` file and comment out line that says `blacklist pcspkr`

...

As mentioned in a comment, Ubuntu does not beep at the terminal by default these days; the information posted above was taken from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/19909).

After you've followed those steps, run the program again and see if that corrects the issue.